# How to write data from next available row when the length of the two rows are different

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I created a macro to parse the "title" and "ingredients" of each recipe from three identical recipe links. This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfRBR.jpg).

If I run the macro for the second time and more, the data are overwritten. It should start writing data from the new row.

I could use lastrow logic to start writing data from the next available row but the problem is the data of the two rows are not of the same length which is why I get stuck.

```vb
Sub GrabContent()
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet
    Dim oTitle As Object, oPosts As Object
    Dim linklist As Variant, url As Variant, R&
    Dim Http As Object: Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    R = 2
        
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("A1:B1") = Array("Title", "Ingredients")
        
    linklist = Array( _
      "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/honey-mustard-chicken-salad-sandwich/", _
      "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/caprese-quinoa-salad/", _
      "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/garlic-beef-and-veggie-ramen/" _
      )
    For Each url In linklist
        With Http
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
            
        Set oTitle = HTML.querySelector("h1.entry-title")
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = oTitle.innerText
            
        Set oPosts = HTML.querySelectorAll(".wprm-recipe-ingredients-container li.wprm-recipe-ingredient")
        For i = 0 To oPosts.Length - 1
            HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oPosts(i).outerHTML
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Cells(R, 2) = HTMLDoc.querySelector("span.wprm-recipe-ingredient-name").innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
            R = R + 1
        Next i
    Next url
End Sub
```

How can I write data from next available row when the length of the two rows are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

respect for a well formulated post ...

Firstly only write headers when cell A1 empty:

```
    '++ Only add titles if sheet empty
    If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A1").Value) Then ws.Range("A1:B1") = Array("Title", "Ingredients")
```

Secondly `Range.CurrentRegion` will return the full extent of joined cells so can help you identify the last used row and so the next available row

```
    R = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
```

so code now looks like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub GrabContent()
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet
    Dim oTitle As Object, oPosts As Object
    Dim linklist As Variant, url As Variant, R&
    Dim Http As Object: Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    '-- set R after headers are output
    'R = 2
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    '++ Only add titles if sheet empty
    If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A1").Value) Then ws.Range("A1:B1") = Array("Title", "Ingredients")
    
    ' ++ Set R to be first free row after exisiting output
    R = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
    
    linklist = Array( _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/honey-mustard-chicken-salad-sandwich/", _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/caprese-quinoa-salad/", _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/garlic-beef-and-veggie-ramen/" _
    )
    For Each url In linklist
        With Http
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        
        Set oTitle = HTML.querySelector("h1.entry-title")
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = oTitle.innerText
        
        Set oPosts = HTML.querySelectorAll(".wprm-recipe-ingredients-container li.wprm-recipe-ingredient")
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To oPosts.Length - 1
            HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oPosts(i).outerHTML
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Cells(R, 2) = HTMLDoc.querySelector("span.wprm-recipe-ingredient-name").innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
            R = R + 1
        Next i
    Next url
End Sub
```

p.s. you need to `Dim i as integer` - I have `Option Explicit` on by default

Comment: Microsoft docs on CurrentRegion - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion - "The current region is a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns"